# Disable double-shift in pycharm

Tags: pycharm

I'd like to know how to disable "double-shift" hotkey that opens "search everywhere" window in pycharm, or at least remap it to something sane.

It gets in my way and disrupts any attempt to work with the editor.

There's no information on the subject anywhere on the internet.

I'm using PyCharm community edition 2016.1.3 on windows 7 64bit.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you want to disable the double-shift binding completely, do this:

### From version 2021.2

1. Go to File | Settings.
2. Click Advanced Settings in the lower left.
3. Click the "Search advanced settings" text box.
4. Type "double".
5. Click the "Disable double modifier key shortcuts" check box.
6. Click OK.

See [Lejia Chen's comment on issue IDEA-161094](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-161094#focus=Comments-27-5093217.0-0) for a graphical illustration.

(Thanks to Vladimir Markiev for mentioning this change.)

### Before version 2021.2

[Konstantin Bulenkov's comment on issue IDEA-161094](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-161094#comment=27-2518218) in the JetBrains YouTrack issue tracker gives the following solution which also works in PyCharm:

1. Press Ctrl+Shift+A to invoke the "Find Action…" dialog.
2. Type "registry".
3. Choose "Registry…" from the list.
4. Find **ide.suppress.double.click.handler** in the list and check the checkbox next to it. (Note that the name is a misnomer; double-clicking with the mouse will not be affected.)
5. Press Close.

This has worked perfectly in PyCharm 2017.3.1 as well as 2019.3.4, and probably up to, but not including, 2021.2.

Comment: **This actually solves the question.** For skeptic people (like me) who think this does something else (like suppress double click to open file or something), this is the description when you select the option in the registry: `IDEA-161094 Option to disable "search everywhere"`. IMO the name `double.click` isn't well-chosen

Comment: Just want to commend you on an excellent answer. You've written it so succinctly that Google actually displays it as a snippet, and the snippet contains the full information. Great work!

Comment: Thanks @Alan! 

Comment: For versions since **2021.2** look for *Disable double modifier key shortcuts* in **Settings > Advanced settings**.

Comment: @VladimirMarkiev Thanks, Vladimir, that was an important change (as the old solution stopped working from version 2021.2)! I adjusted the answer now.

Answer (score 7):

If you go to file > settings > keymap tab and search for "search anywhere" you can remap the key. Once you remap, double shift doesn't seem to open the search dialogue.

For some reason, the double shift tap shortcut doesn't appear in the keymap, and becomes the default again if you remove your custom binding.

Just pick a key you're not using.

Comment: In pycharm 2016.2 it doesn't seem to work anymore. Seems like it cannot be disabled now. I don't get it, it's a really dumb shortcut.

Answer (score 4):

The solutions in this thread don't work in 2021.2.1. The registry option is gone and adding a custom shortcut does not disable double-shift. The solution is to enable the following:

```
Settings | Advanced Settings | Disable double modifier key shortcuts
```

[image: Picture of the option in the settings menu]

More info in this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-161094

Answer (score 3):

Vladimir Kravets suggested fix in the [Youtrack Bugtracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-114933#comment=27-603899) disables this feature. Quote:

> I found workaround.
>
> Open lib/resources.jar/idea/PlatformActions.xml and remove or comment
>   such line:
>
> ```
> <action id="SearchEverywhere" class="com.intellij.ide.actions.SearchEverywhereAction" />
> ```

So close Pycharm, open this Jar with the 7-Zip File Manager, extract the XML file, outcomment the above line, save the file, move it back into the Jar (using the 7-Zip File Manager again), restart Pycharm.

BTW, in that XML file there is also one closing `>` too much in the line above.

Tested with Pycharm 2017.1.2 on Windows 7.

Comment: just what i needed!